# Why are serving an html page and clicking/running it different?

Tags: javascript, html, css, localhost, mamp

This might be a beginner's question, but I am really curious.

I have HTML/CSS/Javascript project that uses several plugins like dataTables.js, jQuery, modernizr.js etc.

The question is, when I run it from the filesystem by clicking it, some elements are very different than running it in the local MAMP server.

Why is this? I thought since it's just html and JS, they should be the same. What am I wrong about?

Comment: different how exactly ? Just guessing here, but does any of javascript talk to a PHP page or any server side script or database, if so, then that's why it's different. If you open the html directly your javascript is not able to talk to the server but when you open through `localhost` the server side script/connection gets called and executed in the appropiate server module to correctly talk back to your javascript.

Comment: it's not my project so I'm not sure what's behind, but the main difference is when it is hosted, the button to check/uncheck columns to be shown in the table is displayed and also only selected columns, but when it's run directly, that button is not shown and all columns are displayed. At the moment, I am guessing the button is not shown because some JS code that talks to server results in an error when run directly and that's why the remaining parts of jQuery code probably are not being called.

Comment: you could look at the JS console (`ctrl`+`shift`+`J` on chrome/firefox) to see if any JS errors/warnings are shown and you can extrapolate based on the error/warning messages to get to the bottom of this.